# Divisibility by 3

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I was reading an article on [Writing an Efficient Method to Check if a Number is Multiple of 3](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-an-efficient-method-to-check-if-a-number-is-multiple-of-3/).

The method explained here is to take the difference between `oddsum` and `evensum` of the number in binary representation. If the difference is divisible by 3 so is the number. I understood why we are doing this, but I am not able to understand why the time complexity is O(log n).

Comment: All this boldface looks kind of like you're shouting...

Comment: I just want to emphasize on what i want to get in the answers.

Comment: The question of "efficiency" is a tricky one here, because it really depends on what kind of operations you can do efficiently. This is a problem which can easily be solved in hardware. With modern microprocessors you are probably better off doing n % 3 == 0, as both the division and comparison are very fast operations. (If you worry about very long numbers, this can be done e.g. 64 bits at a time.) So, the method is a good way to understand some properties of numbers, but it has only limited practical application.

Comment: BTW: What time complexity do **you** think it has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of operations before recursing is bounded by O(log n), because that is the number of bits required to represent `n` and subsequently the number of shift operations required to turn any `n` to zero. The following recursion receives an `n` that is at most `log n / 2`, so its loop has the complexity O(log (log n / 2)). Since this term is less than the initial loop complexity (and all following recursions are even less), it can be omitted. To be precise, the **sum** of all recursions must be less than the initial loop for that to hold, but I'm pretty confident (though I lack the exact proof) that that is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The counting at before recursing takes O(logN) and it reduces the input to logn/2 so following a recurrence equation defining that :-

> T(n) = T(logn/2) + O(logn)
>
> T(n) = logn + log(logn/2) + log(log(logn/2)/2) .....
>
> neglecting 2
>
> T(n) < logn + log(logn) + log(log(logn)) .....
>
> iterative log given by log*n converges very fast where practically
>   log*n < 5
>
> T(n) < logn + log(logn) + log2(n) + log3(n) + log4(n) < 5*logn
>
> T(n) = O(logn)